# iPhone answering machine

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to create an iPhone application to answer incoming voice calls and play audio files back to the caller? If yes, before answering the call, is it possible to determine the caller id?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure that with appropriate programming knowledge it would be possible.  However, Apple and AT&T would probably consider this app to "duplicate existing features" and there is a good chance that it wouldn't get approved for the app store as a result.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible using the SDK. You can most likely do it with a jailbroken app.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone applications (non-jailbreak apps, at least) cannot intercept phone calls. When a phone call is initiated, your app is paused and cannot execute any commands.

Essentially, count on **never** being able to prevent basic functionality of the iPhone. You can't override texting behaviour, Mail.app behaviour, Safari behavior, etc. because Apple wants the user experience to be consistent (not to mention security issues in allowing an app to answer calls on someone's behalf).